# polars python change date

Tags: date, datetime, monthcalendar

I have this dataframe made on the polars library of python :

```
from datetime import date
import polars as pl

my_df = pl.DataFrame({
    'Col1': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    'Col2': [date(2020, 1, 31), date(2020, 1, 31), date(2020, 1, 31),
             date(2020, 1, 31), date(2020, 1, 31), date(2020, 1, 31),
             date(2020, 1, 31), date(2020, 1, 31)],
})
```

I want the date in field 'col2' to change month every time the value in field 'col1' changes.

Could you please help me?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that month=2 and 3 doesn't contain 31 days. Here's working script -

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

from datetime import date


df = pl.DataFrame({
    'Col1': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    'Col2': [date(2020, 1, 25), date(2020, 1, 25), date(2020, 1, 25),
             date(2020, 1, 25), date(2020, 1, 25), date(2020, 1, 25),
             date(2020, 1, 25), date(2020, 1, 25)],
})

df = df.with_columns(pl.Series('Col2_updated', list(map(lambda col1, col2: col2.replace(month=col1), df['Col1'], df['Col2']))))

print(df)
```

Output -

[image]

Comment: Please accept the answer if you feel it solves your concern.